# Why is the set $\{1/2\}\times(1/2, 1]$ not open in the ordered square?

Tags: general-topology

Please refer to Example $3$ of §$16$ of Munkres for details.

My attempt: $\{1/2\}\times(1/2, 1] = [1/2 \times 1/2, 1/2 \times 1]$, which is a closed interval, thus not open in $I \times I$.

I don't really think mine is convincing enough.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: You’re right to worry: an interval in a linearly ordered space can be both closed and open. Your interval is neither: it’s open at the left end and closed at the right end. In interval notation it’s

$$\left(\left\langle\frac12,\frac12\right\rangle,\left\langle\frac12,1\right\rangle\right]\;.$$

The way to show that this one is not open is to find a point that is not in its interior, and there’s only one reasonable candidate, the endpoint $p=\left\langle\frac12,1\right\rangle$.

Let $\prec$ be the strict lexicographic order. Show that if $q=\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$ and $r=\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$, where $q\prec p\prec r$, then the open interval $(q,r)$ in the lexicographically ordered square is not a subset of $\left\{\frac12\right\}\times\left(\frac12,1\right]$. In other words, no matter how you choose a point $q$ that comes before $p$ in the order and another point $r$ that comes after $p$, the basic open set $(q,r)$ doesn’t fit inside the set $\left\{\frac12\right\}\times\left(\frac12,1\right]$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Narcissa: You’re welcome!